# Cloudfront sometimes blank page

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have cloudfront connected to a load balancer that uses an ubuntu server 14.04 ec2 instance. Sometimes when I'm browsing the control panel on my wordpress website I'll just get a blank page and I'll have to hit enter and wait about 30s before I'm taken to the next page. This commonly happens after a "post" request.

Anyone have any ideas? I've had this setup working properly for a while now without problems but after an ubuntu update my server exploded. I had to set some apache worker threads to a lower number, set a mysql swap, remove apport from crashing my server. Then it's like this blank page thing happens to me too.

I also changed my domain name so I had to basically recreate all my stuff on amazon, but I double/triple checked it and it all seems to be the right values like they were before.

This is my cloudfront settings, its long

```
cloudfront settings general

Distribution ID E11KP67NC8KZHO
Log Prefix  -
Delivery Method Web
Cookie Logging  Off
Distribution Status Deployed
Comment -
Price Class Use All Edge Locations (Best Performance)
AWS WAF Web ACL -
State   Enabled
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) 
techstory2.com
SSL Certificate techstory2.com (1f411465-1b8d-42a5-93f4-9cd663330e46)
Domain Name d1cqn6ev1d7d25.cloudfront.net
Custom SSL Client Support   Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)
Default Root Object -
Last Modified   2016-07-22 18:20 UTC-4
Log Bucket


Origins
techstory2balan-595918364.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com

ELB-techstory2balan-595918364       
Origin SSL Protocols
TLSv1.2 enabled
TLSv1.1 enabled
TLSv1 enabled
SSLv3 diabled

Origin Protocol Policy
HTTPS Only selected

HTTP Port
80
HTTPS Port
443

Behaviours
Path PatternDefault (*)     
Origin
ELB-techstory2balan-595918364
Viewer Protocol Policy
Redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Allowed HTTP Methods
GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE

Cached HTTP Methods
GET, HEAD (Cached by default)
OPTIONS

Forward Headers
All

Minimum TTL
0

Maximum TTL
31536000

Default TTL
86400

Forward Cookies
All

Forward Query Strings
Yes

Smooth Streaming
No

Restrict Viewer Access
No

Compress Objects Automatically
Yes
```

Comment: Can you also paste your cloud front setting you are using?

Comment: I copied the cloudfront settings in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the load balancer was hammering my own ec2 instance with around 20 command.php requests per second as seen in my apache2/access.log,

```
72.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:17 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=12926 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7668 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7471 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=9595 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7700 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7356 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7337 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=8858 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=6744 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7757 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
::1 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 125 "-" "Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 OpenSSL/1.0.1f (internal dummy connection)"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7305 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7892 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7214 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7669 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=6415 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=8637 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=12586 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=8546 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=6124 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7005 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=13623 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=8515 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=12445 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=9376 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=5569 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:18 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=13800 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:19 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=7296 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
172.31.7.71 - - [25/Jul/2016:17:21:19 +0000] "POST /remote50/command.php?uid=8520 HTTP/1.1" 500 780 "-" "-"
```

Why it was doing this, I don't know.  All I know is I shutdown the load balancer and cloudfront and now my ec2 instance works properly.  I will try deleting and recreating the load balancer and cloudfront later and hopefully it doesn't ddos my own server next time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have configured your origin protocol policy HTTPS only. This means when a user accesses CloudFront via HTTPS, CloudFront will contact your origin over HTTPS. I would recommend recheck the SSL from he ELB level.

The reason it works some times is that your distribution is not configured to vary on protocol, so if a user made a request over HTTP, said object would be in the CloudFront cache and also be served over HTTPS.

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html
2. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sociallyuncensored.com

Answer (score 1):

Run cloudfront cache invalidation. That was solution for me.